# ¿Por que no guarda los datos? FormData()

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de guardar los datos de un excel, usando un input de tipo file para seleccionarlo, hace poco lo logre hacer sin ajax, y resulto bien; sin embargo no lo he logrado usando Ajax, al investigar leí que para enviar datos de un input de tipo file, se debe de usar FormData() pero no me esta funcionando, les dejo mi código del Ajax.

EL AJAX dentro de mi documento de Vista

```
$(document).ready(function() {   


//-----------Cargar la lista de usuarios dependiendo del perfil----------                   

$("#id_tip").change(function() {

  $("#id_tip option:selected").each(function() {

      id_tip = $('#id_tip').val();

      $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>cHorarios/cargar_usuarios", {

      id_tip : id_tip

      }, 

      function(data) {

         $("#rut_usu").html(data);

        });
      });
    });

 //---------------------fin de la funcion----------------------------------

 //-------Enviamos los datos por Ajax -------------------------------------


 $(function(){

 $('#subida').submit(function(){

  var comprobar = $('#file').val().length;

  if(comprobar>0){

   var formulario = $('#subida');
   var rut_usu;
   var fecha_ini;
   var fecha_ter;
   var archivos = new FormData();  

   archivos.append('rut_usu',rut_usu);
   archivos.append('fecha_ini',fecha_ini);
   archivos.append('fecha_ter',fecha_ter);


   var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>cHorarios/guardar_horario';

   for (var i = 0; i < (formulario.find('input[type=file]').length); i++) { 

    archivos.append((formulario.find('input[type="file"]:eq('+i+')').attr("name")),((formulario.find('input[type="file"]:eq('+i+')')[0]).files[0]));

        }

  $.ajax({


    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, 
    data: archivos,
    processData:false,


    success: function(data){

      if(data == 'OK'){

        $('#respuesta').html('<label style="padding-top:10px; color:green;">Importacion de xlsx exitosa</label>'); 
        return false; 

      }else{

        $('#respuesta').html('<label style="padding-top:10px; color:red;">Error en la importacion del xlsx</label>');
        return false;

      }


    }

  });

  return false;

}else{

  alert('Selecciona un archivo  para importar');

  return false;

   }
 });
});


//-------Fin de el envio de datos-----------------------------------------
});
```

El controlador(Es el mismo de mi post del EXCEL)

```
public function guardar_horario(){


if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {


 $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


 if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
       && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

    // Nombre Temporal del Archivo
    $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    //Lee el Archivo usando ReaderFactory
    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

    //var_dump($reader);

    $reader->setShouldFormatDates(true);

    // Abrimos el archivo
    $reader->open($inputFileName);
    $count = 1;

    //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo
    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {

        // Numero de filas en el documento EXCEL
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

            // Lee los Datos despues del encabezado
            // El encabezado se encuentra en la primera fila
         if($count > 1) {


            $data = array(


              'rut_usu' => $this->input->post('rut_usu'),
              'hrs_ini' => $row[0],
              'hrs_ter' => $row[1],
              'lunes' => $row[2],
              'martes' => $row[3],
              'miercoles' => $row[4],
              'jueves' => $row[5],
              'viernes' => $row[6],
              'sabado' => $row[7],
              'fecha_ini' => $this->input->post('fecha_ini'),
              'fecha_ter' => $this->input->post('fecha_ter')

           ); 


          $this->db->insert('horario',$data);

           } 
            $count++;
         }
     }

       // cerramos el archivo EXCEL
        $reader->close();

    } else {

    echo "Seleccione un tipo de Archivo Valido";
   }

  } else {

  echo "Seleccione un Archivo EXCEL";

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es la siguiente(gracias Cristián Andrés Silva de Programadores Chile)

```
 $('#subida').submit(function() {

 var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>cHorarios/guardar_horario"; 

 var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("subida"));

 $.ajax({

 type: "POST",
 cache: false,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 url: url,
 data: formData,
 success: function(res)

 {

  alert(res);

  }

})

return false; 

});
```